# Problem with accents after generating pdf file with java

Tags: java, linux, pdf, diacritics, pdf-writer

i'm working with liferay 7.2 on local and after generating pdf, working so fine for me

after deploying on test site the pdf is generated without recognizing letters with accents like é
a collegue told me that the problem is caused due to the site which is using linux as a system

i m using a pdf writer folowing this code

```
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);
    Font font_titre = new Font(Font.TIMES_ROMAN, 14, Font.BOLD, coul_bleu);
    ph1 = new Phrase("Activités", font_titre);
```

I'm getting this :

[problem after generating pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJpyW.png)

Comment: What is the character  encoding of the source file ? It should be UTF-8, that will work cross on all OS platforms.

Comment: While indeed the fonts included in a PDF viewer are limited in their character selection, Western European characters  usually are covered, in particular something like an 'é'. Furthermore, the screen shot looks like UTF-8 encoded text being interpreted as if it was Latin-1 encoded. Thus, for a test please replace 'é' by '\u00E9' and test again. If that eventually draws an 'é', it's a mere encoding issue of your code.

Comment: Great! By the way, that most likely means that your code file is saved as UTF-8 but that your Java compiler expects the Java code files to be Latin-1 (or similarly) encoded. As UTF-8 here nowadays is quite standard, you might want to change your compiler call to expect UTF-8 encoded files.